# Issue with Regular expressions in python. Unable to print the exact required content after scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
html = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
images = soup.findAll("img", 
{"src":re.compile("\.\.\/img\/gifts\/img.*\.jpg") })

for image in images:
    x=(image['src'])
    print(x)

    mage = re.findall("^\.\. (\/img\/gifts\/img.*\.jpg)",x)
    print(mage)
```

======================================================================

In the code above the output is 
../img/gifts/img1.jpg
[]
../img/gifts/img2.jpg
[]
../img/gifts/img3.jpg
[]
../img/gifts/img4.jpg
[]
../img/gifts/img6.jpg
[]

however, I put the print(mage) phrase and the code to get rid of the first two dots in the output of print(x)

Can somebody help me with this problem? Why am I getting the empty []. please help me with code if there are any errors

I am using pycharm to run this code

Answer (score 0):

From [`re.findAll`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

> The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups**

In other words, if you are looking to get a complete match you need to get rid of the group, or replace it with non-capturing group:

```
mage = re.findall("^\.\. (?:\/img\/gifts\/img.*\.jpg)",x)
```